# How to make Org writing similar to AUCTeX?

Tags: org-mode, latex, auctex, reftex-mode

I'm deciding whether to use AUCTeX or Org to write my Master's thesis. I tried Org mode with the new Org-cite + Citar package, and I'm very happy about it. Then, trying AUCTeX, I found its RefTeX reference, cross-reference and label capabilities more complete, such as having a TOC, referncing labels, images and equations.

My question is: **is it possible to import these features in Org?** I have heard about Org-ref, but it's poorly documented and (iirc) heavily uses Helm/Ivy (which I'd avoid, having switched to Vertico).

Comment: Possible, almost certainly yes, but it might not happen in time for you to use for writing your thesis. I suggest you take the best fit to your needs as it currently exists and go with that.

Comment: TOC handling is native in org. What do you mean by having a TOC?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/dangom/org-thesis - maybe will be useful.

Comment: Nice explanations on org-cite [here](https://blog.tecosaur.com/tmio/2021-07-31-citations.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet currently is to keep using Org-cite and Citar for citations and use Org-ref v3 for table, figure and equation cross-references within the document. (I have a vague memory that Org-ref was moving toward being completion-system agnostic, but I haven't checked.) An alternative for the second functionality could be [Oxr](https://github.com/bdarcus/oxr), which  is a (WIP?) cross-reference package from the maintainer of Citar. As for TOC I'm not sure what you mean. If you just need a good UI to navigate headings there are several solutions around for Org documents, e.g., Consult has `consult-org-heading`.

Comment: Thanks! for TOC I was looking for something like AUCTeX's `C-c =`. Consult seems ok. Btw, I find org-ref extremely undocumented. Can you point me to some resources?

Comment: Well, I don't know about "extremely undocumented" as it has a [long manual](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref.org),  but maybe you could also look into the author's YouTube video series about Org-ref v3, e.g., [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3u6eTSzHT6s&t=1497s) is a hig-level overview of the system.

Comment: My bad, I've seen the manual but I struggled to export it due to different errors/missing parts. Right now, after your comment, I noticed the section "Build notes", with instructions. I'll have a look at it, thanks!